# Spring data jpa query methods with criteria api

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have been using spring data JPA with mysql. I mostly use query methods as below :

```
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Long> {

    Vehicle findByRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber);

    Vehicle findByDriver(Driver driver);

    Vehicle findByNaturalId(String naturalId);


}
```

But now for some usecase I want to criteria api as below :

```
@Repository
public class VehicleCriteriaRepository {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public VehicleCriteriaRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Vehicle find(String naturalId) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Vehicle> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Vehicle.class);
        Root<Vehicle> vehicleRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Vehicle.class);

        CriteriaQuery<Vehicle> registrationNumber = criteriaQuery
                .select(vehicleRoot)
                .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(vehicleRoot.get("naturalId"), naturalId));
        Vehicle singleResult = entityManager.createQuery(registrationNumber).getSingleResult();
        return singleResult;
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand that how can I use both of them together. Because if I want to use criteria api, I'll have to make a concrete class. And in case I make a concrete class I could not understand how will I be able to use jpa query methods, as if I implement the interface, I'll have to provide an implementation.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: What's wrong with having both?

Comment: There are tutorials covering this. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries and others.

Comment: I thought that why to have two repositories for the same entity. If possible i wanted to have/encapsulate all repo related logic in one single repo

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring JPA Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications). They will provide you the flexibility of using the Spring repository with JPA's criteria builder.

It is as simple as making your repository extending the interface `JpaSpecificationExecutor`.

```
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Vehicle> {
    ....
}
```

Then you can query your repository using anonymous implementation of an specification or you can implement it as well, whatever suits you best.

An anonymous implementation will be something like below.

```
@Autowired
VehicleRepository vehicleRepository;

// somewhere in some methods
vehicleRepository.findOne((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> 
    criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("naturalId"), naturalId)
);
```